# PGP encryption natively or library for Apex

Tags: apex, encryption

Is there any way to support PGP encryption in Salesforce. I have looked into this question [PGP Encryption in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25332/pgp-encryption-in-apex) but just wanted to confirm is there any new changes that might have allowed PGP in Apex.

Comment: No new changes with respect to Apex but you can [do it in Javascript](https://openpgpjs.org/)

Comment: @identigral thanks. But I need it for apex rest endpoint. So cann't use JS library.

Comment: Javascript can communicate with server-side Apex code.

Comment: @identigral i have to to create a apex rest endpoint, which will encrypt some data using private keys and return it back. In this case can we use JS somehow?

Comment: One option might be calling out from your Apex REST service to another endpoint (also hosted in SF) and sending it plaintext (to encrypt). The other endpoint will return HTML with JS-encrypted text embedded in there . Your Apex REST service can parse the result out of the HTML.

Comment: @ManjotSingh: Did you managed to do PGP encryption through apex?